# Function of a continuous variable using cdf method

Tags: probability, random-variables, self-learning

I'm studying for my exam tomorrow, and I ran into this question.

Let Y be an exponential random variable with parameter $\tau > 0$. Compute the cdf and pdf of $F_W$ where $W = Y^3$

The solution states the cdf as $1 - e^{\frac{-y^\frac{1}{3}}{t}}$ because $F_Y =1 - e^{\frac{y}{\tau}}$. $P[W \leq w] = P[Y^3 \leq w] = P[Y \leq y^{\frac{1}{3}}] = 1 - e^{\frac{-y^\frac{1}{3}}{t}}$

I tried achieving the same results with the following logic:
$P[W \leq w] = P[Y^3 \leq w] = P[Y \leq w^{\frac{1}{3}}] = \int_{0}^{w^\frac{1}{3}} \frac{1}{\tau} e^{-\frac{y}{\tau}}dy =\left(e^{-\frac{\sqrt[3]{w}}{\tau}}-1\right)\tau+\frac{\sqrt[3]{w}}{\tau}$

However this does not return the same result. Does anyone know why my method did not return the correct result?

Comment: I'm greatly confused by how you did that integration. The rest of it makes sense, assuming that $\tau=E[Y]$ instead of $\tau^{-1}=E[Y]$.

Comment: @Ian could you elaborate on your confusion?

Comment: Where did $x$ come from, for example? Also, you switched from $w$ over to $y$ for no particular reason. It would have been better to define $y=w^{1/3}$ instead, or just to stick with the variable $w$.

Comment: @Ian That was a typo, I've edited the x's to be $\tau$

Comment: OK, well, now your integration is still wrong, but that's the only thing that went awry besides changing from $w$ to $y$ (and then apparently back to $w$ and back to $y$ again...)

Comment: @Ian I edited the variable changes, does this flow more logically?

Comment: You still have a couple of $y$'s on the end. The integration is a bigger problem, though.

Comment: @Ian Could you explain what is wrong with the integration?

Comment: That last term totally shouldn't be there, and the $\tau$ on the outside of the first term should be canceled out by the $1/\tau$ that was in the integration, and there should be a minus sign as well.

Comment: @Ian That was the answer generated from a computer, which is why I am struggling with why the answer generated differs so much from the solution provided

Comment: You probably confused the computer with your input, I'd have to see the code to see why. Still, it's not hard to integrate an exponential function, you should not have needed a CAS for this problem.